# How to remove extra double quotes and escape character from array

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to display the array as a response to the API get call.  The content of the array is the output of shell script. When I'm trying to display the array using response entity, it adds the extra colon and slashes for each line in the array, not sure how.

**Java code**

```
@GetMapping("/awsregions/getList")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<AwsRegionList> getAllAWSRegions() throws Exception {

    String prochelmline;
    String prochelmline1;

    String jsonResponse;

    List<String> regions = new ArrayList<>();
    
    AwsRegionList reglist = new AwsRegionList();

    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/app/awsregions.sh");
    proc.waitFor();

    InputStream stdout1 = proc.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout1));
    while ((prochelmline = reader1.readLine()) != null) {
        if (prochelmline != null) {
        //  prochelmline1 = prochelmline;
            regions.add(prochelmline);

        }
    }

    reglist.setListOfAwsRegion(regions);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(reglist);
}
```

**Model class**

```
public class AwsRegionList implements Serializable  {   
    @ArraySchema(
              schema = @Schema(implementation = AwsRegionList.class,
              description = "Get location information"))
    
    List<String> listOfAwsRegion = new ArrayList<String>();
    public List<String> getListOfAwsRegion() {
        return listOfAwsRegion;
    }
    public void setListOfAwsRegion(List<String> listOfAwsRegion) {
        this.listOfAwsRegion = listOfAwsRegion;
    }
}
```

The content of the shell script is as below:

```bash
aws ec2 describe-regions --all-regions --no-cli-pager | grep RegionName | cut -b 27-50 | sed 's/.$//'
```

The output it prints is:

```
"ap-south-2"
"ap-south-1"
"eu-south-1"
"eu-south-2"
"me-central-1"
"il-central-1"
"ca-central-1"
"eu-central-1"
"eu-central-2"
"us-west-1"
"us-west-2"
"af-south-1"
"eu-north-1"
"eu-west-3"
"eu-west-2"
"eu-west-1"
"ap-northeast-3"
"ap-northeast-2"
"me-south-1"
"ap-northeast-1"
"sa-east-1"
"ap-east-1"
"ca-west-1"
"ap-southeast-1"
"ap-southeast-2"
"ap-southeast-3"
"ap-southeast-4"
"us-east-1"
"us-east-2"
```

The output of get API call in swagger is like below:

```json
{
  "listOfAwsRegion": [
    "\"ap-south-2\"",
    "\"ap-south-1\"",
    "\"eu-south-1\"",
    "\"eu-south-2\"",
    "\"me-central-1\"",
    "\"il-central-1\"",
    "\"ca-central-1\"",
    "\"eu-central-1\"",
    "\"eu-central-2\"",
    "\"us-west-1\"",
    "\"us-west-2\"",
    "\"af-south-1\"",
    "\"eu-north-1\"",
    "\"eu-west-3\"",
    "\"eu-west-2\"",
    "\"eu-west-1\"",
    "\"ap-northeast-3\"",
    "\"ap-northeast-2\"",
    "\"me-south-1\"",
    "\"ap-northeast-1\"",
    "\"sa-east-1\"",
    "\"ap-east-1\"",
    "\"ca-west-1\"",
    "\"ap-southeast-1\"",
    "\"ap-southeast-2\"",
    "\"ap-southeast-3\"",
    "\"ap-southeast-4\"",
    "\"us-east-1\"",
    "\"us-east-2\""
  ]
}
```

I don't understand why the extra double quotes and slashes are coming. In the original shell script output, it is not there. Then how it is being added? Can we use Gson library for pretty printing? Any example code would be appreciated.

Comment: There are no "extra" double quotes. Your original input has double quotes. If you serialize some string value in JSON, you get: "<string value>", if <string value> contains double quotes, they are escaped. For example, the string value `has " double quote`, in JSON becomes `"has \" double quote"`. You need to strip the double quotes from your original input if you don't want them to occur escaped in your output.

Comment: Think about it: If JSON couldn't escape double quotes, how would it distinguish between actual double quotes and those indicating that a `String` starts/ends?

Answer (score 0):

As the comments mentioned the quotes came from the Reader and need to be removed manually if you want to get rid of them.

And also two other things I like to add:

1. You don't need to check a second time for `prochelmline` to be not null, you already did it in the condition of the while loop.
2. It's good practice to declare variables as late in the code as possible (Java allows that)

```java
final List<String> regions = new ArrayList<>();
String prochelmline;
while ((prochelmline = reader1.readLine()) != null) {
    final var withoutQuotations = prochelmline.substring(1, prochelmline.length() - 1);
    regions.add(withoutQuotations);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The response you get is a standard JSON response. Your class `AwsRegionList` was serialized into JSON String - This is standard behaviour. So, all you need to do is to deserialize your string back to `AwsRegionList` instance. To do this you can use any Json library. The most often used ones are Json-Jackson library and Gson library. I personally prefer Jackson. To deserialize your JSON string to your `AwsRegionList` class you will need to do this:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
AwsRegionList awsRegionList; 
try {
  awsRegionList = om.readValue(jsonString, AwsRegionList.class);
} catch(JsonProcessingException jpe) {
  ...
}
```

You will need to include Json-Jackson dependencies into your project if they already not included. Here is a [link to Javadoc of ObjectMapper's readValue method](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-). 
While this is simple enough there is an even simpler way. I wrote my own simple wrapper over `ObjectMapper` class called JsonUtils. If you want to use this class your code might become even simpler:

```
AwsRegionList awsRegionList; 
try {
  awsRegionList = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString(jsonStr, AwsRegionList.class);
} catch(IOException ioe) {
  ...
}
```

Here you don't need to instantiate `ObjectMapper` class or `JsonUtils` class as method `JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString()` is a static method. Here is [the Javadoc for JsonUtils class](https://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html). To use this class you have to include a dependency for MgntUtils library written and maintained by me. The dependency could be found [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or the library itself as a jar (and also source code and Javadoc could be found on the [GitHub](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases). If you choose to use the MgntUtils library it already includes necessary Json lib dependencies, so you don't have to worry about it.